# Get user claims before any page loads on external ADFS login

Tags: c#, asp.net, ws-federation, adfs3.0

What I'm trying to do is accessing user claims which returns from ADFS login. ADFS returns username and with that username I have to run a query to another DB to get user information and store it. I don't really know where to do that and what the best practice is. I can access user claims in the view controller like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    ClaimsPrincipal user = ctx.Authentication.User;
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;
    return View();
}
```

But what I need to do is as I said access claims like in global.asax.cs or startup.cs to store user information before the application runs.

This is my Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add an event handler to the `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions` value in our startup file.

This happens immediately after the security token has been validated.

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
{
    MetadataAddress = MetadataAddress,

    Wtrealm = Wtrealm,
    Wreply = CallbackPath,
    Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        SecurityTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
        {
           ClaimsIdentity identity = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
           DoSomethingWithLoggedInUser(identity);
        }
     }
};
```

Comment: It kinda works to get user information there, but now I have another problem. Authentication seems like lifetime and where ever I try to connect to the server it thinks that I am logged in anyway and not redirecting to the ADFS authorization.

I wonder if I should change CookieAuthenticationDefaults to WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults to solve it or any idea what can be wrong in my code?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, had something wrong with the build. Anyway this solved it! Thank you.